# how can i use re.findall to match a substring using python regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have the following string variable called strSourceCode in python3.x,

```
'uint256 private constant _tTotal = 100000000 * 10**9;
uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
_maxTxAmount = 300000000 * 10**9;'
```

I would like to match '100000000 * 10**' and'300000000 * 10**' and it should give me the following two lines as output using re.findall

```
uint256 private constant _tTotal = 100000000 * 10**9;
_maxTxAmount = 300000000 * 10**9;
```

Currently i have the following code:

```
pattern = '^.*[0-9]0{4,}.*$'
matches = re.findall(pattern, strSourceCode, re.MULTILINE)
```

which falsely outputs as:

```
_maxTxAmount = 300000000 * 10**9;0000 * 10**9;
```

Comment: Your regex starts with `^` and ends with `$`, so it'll match entire lines that have a digit followed by at least four zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `re.findall` here in multiline mode:

```py
inp = """uint256 private constant _tTotal = 100000000 * 10**9;
uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
_maxTxAmount = 300000000 * 10**9;"""

lines = re.findall(r'^.*\d+\s*\*\s*\d+\*\*\d+.*$', inp, flags=re.M)
print(lines)
```

This prints:

```
['uint256 private constant _tTotal = 100000000 * 10**9;',
 '_maxTxAmount = 300000000 * 10**9;']
```

The regex pattern used here attempts to find any line containing an integer multiplied by 10 to some integer power.

Comment: thank you very much!! it worked! Can you explain what the \s single line means in this code?

Comment: @abid The `\s*` means zero or more whitespace characters.  For your specific input you may think of `\s*` as meaning zero or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```py
pattern = '[0-9]0{4,}[0-9\s*]*'
matches = re.findall(pattern, strSourceCode, re.MULTILINE)
```

It doesn't match entire lines.
The pattern searches for digits followed by at least four zeroes which is then followed by any number of spaces, digits, and `*` characters.

If you want to match exactly  `* 10**` after you big number you can do this:

```py
pattern = '[0-9]0{4,} \* 10\*\*'
matches = re.findall(pattern, strSourceCode, re.MULTILINE)
```